# I have a List[(List[A], List[R])] - a List of a tuple of two Lists of objects A and R respectively. How do I "flatten" the List[R] for each List[A]?

Tags: list, scala, data-structures, flatten

I have a **List[(List[A], List[R])]** - *a List of a tuple of two Lists of objects A and R respectively.*

For example, `List[([A1, A2], [R1, R2, R3])]`

What I want to do is convert this into a `List[(List[A], R)]` for every R object. So basically, make a `List[Tuple2]` where the R object is “flattened” for the list of A objects.

**Example** - For the above example, the overall List should get divided into 3 sublists looking like:

```
List[([A1, A2], R1)]
List[([A1, A2], R2)]
List[([A1, A2], R3)]
```

I need to get every single R element given any list of A elements. The reason for this is that the A elements can contain *nested sub-A* elements and *multiple R elements*, so I need to segregate each R as being part of a List[A].

So far, this is what I’ve tried but I have no idea how to do the "flatten" part of my question:

```
lazy val rules: List[(List[A], R)] = {
    //listOfA = List[A1, A2, A3,…]
    //listOfR = List[R1, R2, R3, …]
    val fromA = listOfA.map { A => (List(A.description) ++ A.subGroups.map(_.description), A.rules) } // Currently: List[(List[A], List[R])]  Required: List[(List[A], R)]
    val fromR = listOfR.map { r => (Nil, r) } // List[(Nil, R)]
    fromA ++ fromR
}
```

This is the definition for the A case class:

`case class A(description: Descriptor, rules: List[R], subGroups: List[A])`

… and case class R just contains the List[R] directly. In case of the `fromR` defintion, there is *no List[A] present hence that is substituted by Nil* to represent *blank* List[A].

As you can see, for the `val fromR` I can just get the individual R by map-ing it as I have done in fromR. I need to get a combined result from `fromA ++ fromR` (as it may be possible that my input contains a mix of *R's within A* and *direct R's*).

My problem is with the `fromA` definition. So far, I have only been able to get the List[R] for every List[A]. How can I segregate each R for every List[A]… the problem is mainly with the `A.rules` definition.

Please help as I am new to Scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I got lost in the question a bit, after the explanation of the problem, but I'm assuming you want to convert a `List[(List[A], List[R])]` into a `List[(List[A], R)]` for each `R` in the list. A nice and easy way to do this would be to use for comprehensions:

```scala
val result: List[(List[A], R)] = for {
    (as, rs) <- firstList
    r <- rs
  } yield (as, r)
```

You can also use the equivalent approach, but with `flatMap`, `map`:

```scala
val result: List[(List[A], R)] = firstList.flatMap { case (as, rs) => 
  rs.map {r => 
    (as, r)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I used the for-comprehension method you suggested and that does exactly what I need it to!